# How do I reference an image in my stencil theme

Tags: bigcommerce

I am wondering how to correctly reference an image in my scss for my stencil theme I am working on. It works locally but when I upload my theme to bigcommerce it gives a 404 error.

`background: url('../img/header-bg.png') no-repeat;`
`background: url('/assets/img/header-bg.png') no-repeat;`

Those both work locally but both result in a 404 when I upload my theme. I have included the image in that directory and everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same issue you are experiencing, and I'm not 100% sure what the BC recommended way to reference background images in CSS.

Assuming you are placing the images in your assets/img directory I've found that calling `background:url('../img/header-bg.png')` like this has worked both locally, and in production.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So, I found out I wasn't enabling the correct theme on production and the `background: url('../img/header-bg.png') no-repeat;` was working. Can you try it on yours to see if it works? I think the relative path is the correct way to do this.

Comment: Great, if you can update your answer to use the shorter relative path I will mark your answer correct. Thanks for helping!